# Comparison test $\frac{n^2}{n^3+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am working through the above problem and have not gotten too far:

for large n $$\frac{n^2}{n^3+1} \approx \frac{n^2}{n^3} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Now the next step in the solution given to me was:

$$\frac{n^2}{n^3+1} \ge \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3} = \frac{1}{2n}$$

I understand the aim is to compare our unknown with a known series but I don't understand the reasoning behind this line. Where did the second $n^3$ come from and what happened to the $+1$?

Thank you

Comment: there is no simple n in the denominator, it is n cubed, you must have copied it wrong

Comment: once you fix that you know that the series with 'general' term 1/n is divergent and your own series' general term is greater than 1/2n so it must also be divergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ n \ge 1 $, then $ n^3 \ge 1 $. Increasing the denominator decreases the value, so:

$$ \frac{n^2}{n^3 + 1} \ge \frac{n^2}{n^3 + n^3} $$